# Clearing a vector<pointer> and then reusing it

Tags: c++, exception, vector, polymorphism, virtual

Ok, so I have a class called Company() that stores a `vector<pointer>;` (private)

Then I have a base class called StaffMember() that has two dervived classes
(Manager and Casual) that are stored in the vector

I want to be able to clear the vector when editing the list or deleting from it but when I use function such as `Company::StaffMembers.clear();` it crashes and throws a

*"Unhandled exception at 0x00e182f4 in Payroll System.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000005."*

exception at me!

What am I doing wrong!

---

### Company.h

```
#include "StaffMember.h"
#include "Manager.h"
#include "Casual.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Company
{
private:
    vector<StaffMember*> StaffMembers;
public:
    Company();
    void addEmployee( StaffMember* pp );

    void editEmployee( int id, string fname, string lname, double salary );
    void editEmployee( int id, string fname, string lname, int hours, double rate );

    void deleteEmployee( int id );
    StaffMember* getStaffMember( int id );
    int StaffMemberCount();
};
```

---

### Company.cpp

```
void Company::deleteEmployee( int id )
{
    // Impossible
    // Can not delete from vector

    // index will be the id of the employee
    int index = (-1);
    int size = Company::StaffMembers.size();

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        // If the current member's id is the same as the one we are looking for
        if(Company::StaffMembers[i]->getID()==id)
        {
            index=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Index is the id of the Employee we wish to delete
    Company::StaffMembers.erase(Company::StaffMembers.begin() + index );
}
```

Comment: There's no call to "clear()" in the code posted ...

Comment: Not answering but erase the way you have it, won't delete just the one with the given id, but everyone till that point.

Comment: @George: No, it won't.  It will only erase one element.  If he had `x.erase(x.begin(), x.begin() + index)`, then it would do what you say.

Comment: Ah my bad. I thought + was a comma... Sorry

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you need to make sure a correct `id` has been found.  Check that `index != -1` before you perform the `erase`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your program is crashing on this line:

```
       if(Company::StaffMembers[i]->getID()==id)
```

because one of the elements in your vector is `null`. But that's just a guess.

You should really run your code in a debugger, once you know the line of code you're crashing on it gets much easier to spot the problem.